# Working with dial view in SwiftUI with drag gesture and displaying value of selected number

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm new to SwiftUI and what I trying to build is a dial view like this.

As you can see it has:

- a view indicator which is for displaying the currently selected value from the user.
- `CircularDialView` with all the numbers to chose from.
- text view for displaying actual selected number

Maximum what I tried to accomplish is that for now `CircularDialView` is intractable with a two-finger drag gesture and for the rest, I have no even close idea how to do it.

Please help, because I tried everything I could and have to say it's super hard to do with SwiftUI

[image]

Here's the code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: 4, height: 25)
                .padding()
                
            CircularDialView()
                
            Text("\(1)")
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .padding()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct ClockText: View {
    
    var numbers: [String]
    var angle: CGFloat
    
    private struct IdentifiableNumbers: Identifiable {
        var id: Int
        var number: String
    }
    
    private var dataSource: [IdentifiableNumbers] {
        numbers.enumerated().map { IdentifiableNumbers(id: $0, number: $1) }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
                ForEach(dataSource) {
                    Text("\($0.number)")
                        .position(position(for: $0.id, in: geometry.frame(in: .local)))
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func position(for index: Int, in rect: CGRect) -> CGPoint {
        
        let rect = rect.insetBy(dx: angle, dy: angle)
        let angle = ((2 * .pi) / CGFloat(numbers.count) * CGFloat(index)) - .pi / 2
        let radius = min(rect.width, rect.height) / 2
        
        return CGPoint(x: rect.midX + radius * cos(angle),
                       y: rect.midY + radius * sin(angle))
    }
}


struct CircularDialView: View {
    @State private var rotateState: Double = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 5)
                .frame(width: 250, height: 250, alignment: .center)
            
            ClockText(
                numbers: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].map {"\($0)"},
                angle: 45
            )
            .font(.system(size: 20))
            .frame(width: 290, height: 290, alignment: .center)
        }
        .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: rotateState))
        .gesture(
            RotationGesture()
                .simultaneously(with: DragGesture())
                    .onChanged { value in
                        self.rotateState = value.first?.degrees ?? rotateState
                    }
        )
    }
}
```